# creating arrays of results based upon chunks of time

Tags: postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an app that has lots of sensor_events being saved; I'd like to get results by a date then map those into chunks of 15 minute times... this is not the same as doing a group by in postgres as that would only return something averaged and I need the specific events...

What I'm thinking is given a day I get the beginning_of_day and split it up as 15 minute chunks as keys to a hash of arrays ie

```
    def return_time_chunk_hash
    t=Date.today
    st = t.beginning_of_day
    times = Hash.new
    while st<t.end_of_day
        times[st.to_formatted_s(:time)] = Array.new
        st = st + 15.minutes
    end
    return times
end
```

And from that I would compare the sensor_events created_at date, find which bucket it belonged to and plop it in there. Once I've got it that way I know whether or not a chunk has any (.count) and if so can do all the data manipulation on the specific events.

Does this seem nutty? Is there a simpler way I'm not seeing?

**Update:**
I liked the way jgraft was thinking but thought it wouldn't work as I'd have to do multiple queries based upon the group column flag, but then I thought of the group_by of Enumerable so I tried something like this in the actual SensorEvent model:

```
def chunk
    Time.at((self.created_at.to_f / 15.minutes).floor * 15.minutes).to_formatted_s(:time)
end
```

This allows me to get all the sensor events I need as usual (ie `@se=SensorEvent.where(sensor_id: 10)`)  but then I could do `@se.group_by(&:chunk)`  and I get those singular events grouped into a hash ie:

```
    {"13:30"=>
  [#<SensorEvent:0x007ffac0128438
    id: 25006,
    force: 0.0,
    xaccel: 502.0,
    yaccel: 495.0,
    zaccel: 616.0,
    battery: 0.0,
    position: 25.0,
    created_at: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 13:33:37 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 15:51:32 EDT -04:00,
    deviceID: "D36330135FE3D36",
    location: 3,
    sensor_id: 10>,
   #<SensorEvent:0x007ffac0128140
    id: 25007,
    force: 0.0,
    xaccel: 502.0,
    yaccel: 495.0,
    zaccel: 616.0,
    battery: 0.0,
    position: 27.0,
    created_at: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 13:39:46 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 15:51:32 EDT -04:00,
    deviceID: "D36330135FE3D36",
    location: 3,
    sensor_id: 10>,
   .........
```

The trouble is of course not every chunk of time might be created since there was no event to spawn it; also that being a hash it's not sorted in anyway:

```
res.keys
=> ["13:30",
 "13:45",
 "14:00",
 "13:00",
 "15:45",
 "16:00",
 "16:15",
 "16:45",
 "17:00",
 "17:15",
 "17:30",
 "14:15",
 "14:30",
```

I have to do calculations on the chunks of events; I might keep a master TIMECHUNKS array to compare / lookup in order...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Can you show your input data and a sample of the desired results, made up by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a column to the `sensor_events` table that specifies which block it belongs to?  Would basically give you an array as you could do a query like:

`SensorEvent.where(date: Date.today, block: 1)`

and return a relation of the data in an array-esque format.

You could just add an after_create callback to the `SensorEvents` model that sets the `block` column.

```
class SensorEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_block

  private

  def set_block
    value = ((4 * created_at.hour) + (created_at.min.to_f / 15).ceil).to_i
    self.update_columns(block: value)
end
```